# @PrePersist, @PreUpdate Neo4 entities create/update event interceptors

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

In my Spring Boot, Neo4j application I'd like to automatically update createDate and updateDate of my Neo4j Entity

```
@NodeEntity
public class Product {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed
    private String name;

    private Date createDate;

    private Date updateDate;

    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate() {
        createDate = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onUpdate() {    
        updateDate = new Date();
    }

}
```

but @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations don't work here.

How it can be achieved in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use application level `BeforeSaveListener` and `AfterSaveListener`

see the example here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.3.0.RC1/reference/html/#lifecycle_events

Comment: Hi Michael, I know in SDN 6 there is BeforeBindCallback but how can we differentiate between a create, update or delete operation?